# C Program - Double returns zero

Tags: c, double, scanf

This is the C program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void){

    double voltage, resistance;
    printf("Enter your Voltage: ");
    scanf("%f", &voltage);
    printf("Enter your Resistance: ");
    scanf("%f", &resistance);
    double amps = voltage / resistance;
    printf("With voltage %f and Ohm %fohms, amps is equal to %f \n", voltage, resistance, amps);
    return 0;
}
```

Why is voltage and resistance variables returning values of 0.00?

Comment: Hey thanks that worked, can you please explain what adding the 'l' does?

Comment: You might like to RTFM on `scanf()`: http://www.iso-9899.info/n1570.html#6.2.5p28

Comment: Your compiler should have warned on the mismatch between format-specifier and the type of argument passed. If not increase its warning level. Take warnings serious.

Comment: OT: Your result string is missing units for voltage and current, as well as the input prompts do. The unit for resistance is not "ohms" but "Ohm", short Ω.

Answer (score 5):

For [`scanf` (and family)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) the format `"%f"` is for `float`, to get a `double` you need a "long" `float` which have the format-prefix `l` as in `"%lf"`.

---

It should be noted that for printing floating point values with `printf`, all `float` arguments will be *promoted* to `double`. Which means that for `printf` there's no difference between `%f` and `%lf`.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `%lf` in your scanf.

This worked nice for me:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void){

double voltage, resistance;
printf("Enter your Voltage: ");
scanf("%lf", &voltage);
printf("Enter your Resistance: ");
scanf("%lf", &resistance);
double amps = voltage / resistance;
printf("With voltage %f and Ohm %fohms, amps is equal to %f \n", voltage, resistance, amps);
return 0;
}
```